# Cant run OpenCV android app on my divice

Tags: android, opencv, opencv3.1

I'm making an app using android and opencv.
When I run the app on lg g3 opencv is work,
but when I run on galaxy s7 I get the message "opencv was not initialised correctly Application will be shut down" :(
Can someone help please?

```
    compileSdkVersion 24
buildToolsVersion "22.0.1"

defaultConfig {
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 24
    versionCode 2411
    versionName "2.4.11"
}
```

opencv version-3.1

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7FaEX.jpg)

Comment: install the packages from "opencv-3.2.0-android-sdk\OpenCV-android-sdk\apk " in your divice!

Answer (score 0):

did you install OpenCV Manager on your device?

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.opencv.engine&hl=en

Comment: @HilaGavriel did you import the correct processor architecture type to ur opencv library?

Answer (score 0):

check your permissions, does the app require camera use? see what the logcat says on the monitor when you try to run the app.